# Any problems from copying system32 into syswow64?

Tags: windows-7, batch, batch-file, dll

I ran a `.bat` file as an administrator. The `.bat` file said to copy all `.dll` files from the current directory to the `syswow64` directory. Something like:

```
copy *.dll c:\windows\syswow64
```

Unfortunately, running it as an administrator set the current directory to `c:\windows\system32` rather than the directory that the `.bat` file was in, so it caused `.dll` files in `system32` to be copied to `syswow64`. The output showed lots of `.dll` filenames, but also a lot of `Access Denied.`s. I terminated the batch as soon as I noticed it was copying something other than the 7 files I had intended to copy.

Is this harmless for that station, or is it problematic? Is there a way to restore the `syswow64` folder, or should I not bother? Is there even a way to tell if any `.dll` files have been affected?

Comment: That sounds like a horrible idea.

Comment: You might look into using the %~dp0 variable in your batch file to obtain the drive and path that the batch file was started from, rather than assume  the current path at start up is the path of the batch file.

Comment: @BeowulfNode42, Agreed. If you're doing something this questionable you should consider hard coding the directory rather than letting it "assume the current path." `%~dp0` will give you the current drive and path. `%~d0` will give you just the current drive, you can add `\specific\path` to that. You can also use `%CD%` and you will get the current directory, similar to `%~dp0` except `%CD%` can be used in batch files or directly in the CMD prompt whereas `%~dp0` variables are a `.bat` feature.

Comment: @BiTinerary %0 is the full drive, path, filename and extension of the batch file currently running. %~dp0 is just he drive and path to the batch file currently running. It has nothing to do with the current path. try a batch file on your desktop with the lines
`cd /d c:\windows` then on the next line
`echo %~dp0`

Comment: I never mentioned "`%0`" though.... I know what each of those envars do seeing as how I've used them dozens of times... am I missing/misunderstanding something? My descriptive phrasing may be off, for sure. However I was trying more to describe the application of the envars rather than the nuances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be serious problems in the near future.

Confusingly enough, `SysWOW64` holds 32-bit DLLs for use by 32-bit applications that you run, while the `System32` folder has 64-bit binaries.

DLL files that are in use or already exist were not replaced, but there are probably a bunch of 64-bit DLLs that are in a folder where only 32-bit binaries are supposed to be loaded (very bad).

Rebooting could have consequences. You should perform `sfc /scannow` as soon as possible to minimize any loss of system integrity.

Comment: unless the /y switch was used to "Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file." then there will just be extra files in the SysWoW64 folder.

Comment: Oh that's right, I forgot to factor that in. Thanks.

Comment: I guess I'll accept this answer; I wonder though what you're specific reasoning for "very bad" is? It's probably not good, but *why* is it bad?

Comment: @Sahuagin It can confuse programs that depend on DLL detection and lead to random anomalous behavior in the future (caused by program specific behavior).

Answer (score 1):

If they weren't named after system files it will be ok as noting will try to use them. If they were named after system files, as is likely, they will all Access Deny as noone has access to overwrite system files including administrators.

```
C:\Users\User>icacls c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe
c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(F)
                                BUILTIN\Administrators:(RX)
                                NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(RX)
                                BUILTIN\Users:(RX)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

As you can see only TrustedInstaller (the setup/windows update security pseudo user) has permissions to overwrite.

An admin must take ownership, give themselves permission, before being able to overwrite.